# arXiv's compilation introduces underfull \hboxes in bibliography due to hyperlinks

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, arxiv

When I compile with `MikTex` on my computer, my bibliography compiles without issue:

[image]

When `arXiv` compiles it, i get `underfull hboxes` such as

[image]

bib entries:

```
@article{Kogut:1974ag,
  author         = "Kogut, John B. and Susskind, Leonard",
  title          = "{Hamiltonian Formulation of Wilson's Lattice Gauge
                    Theories}",
  journal        = "Phys. Rev.",
  volume         = "D11",
  year           = "1975",
  pages          = "395-408",
  doi            = "10.1103/PhysRevD.11.395",
  reportNumber   = "Print-74-1186 (CORNELL)",
  SLACcitation   = "%%CITATION = PHRVA,D11,395;%%"
}
```

I am using `bibtex` with `revtex4-1` which I believe uses natbib. I load `hyperref` and `microtype`.
I would prefer not to typeset the bibliography ragged right. Using `breaklinks` for `hyperref` does fix the typesetting, but at the unacceptable cost of actually breaking the links themselves, not just the text.

Edit: problem is resolved by submitting `pdf` figures rather than `eps`--the latter must lead to a compilation route that causes issue. The `tex` file itself did not need to be modified.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.